Why my Read Aloud voice is changing between two paragraph in MS Word using Office 365 subscription?
I have a Word document with only two lines as below.
Word Number 2 is. Acquaintance. spelled as

Word Number 2 is. Acquaintance. spelled as a c q u a i n t a n c e

When I click speak Aloud, it speaks line 1 in British tone and line 2 in some European tone.
Please can someone guide how to stick to a British tone only?

that's a quick fix... I tried it myself and it worked!
Just select your line 2 and change the language to British English.
How to change:

Select the language tool that must appear at the bottom left side of the status bar.
A dialog box "Language" will appear. Under "Mark selected text as:", choose "English (United Kingdom)".
Disable "Detect language automatically"
Click "OK"

